# Conditional Labeling based on attributes in ArcGIS 10

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, labeling

I am trying to label a street centerline layer with a condition based on street width.  I am using the Python parser and I can't figure out this simple logic.  Neither of these questions address how to accomplish this within the "Label Expression" window of ArcGis using Python:

[Customizing label features using arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22725/customizing-label-features-using-arcpy/23012#23012)

[Displaying combined data values in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25896/displaying-combined-data-values-in-arcmap/25898#25898)

My attempt at it looks like this:

```
def FindLabel ( [NAME] ):
  if [WIDTH] > 30
  return [NAME]
```

GIS returns me an error when I try this.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a *Label Class* with a *SQL Query* is an alternative to using *label expressions with python*.

The SQL Expression is quite simple:

```
[WIDTH] > 30
```

In [ArcGIS help you find a detailed step-by-step instruction to use a SQL Query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_label_classes_to_label_features_from_the_same_layer_differently/00s80000000v000000/) within a label class.

Comment: (+1) Hmm, I never knew about this. It seems like it would be simpler (and probably faster) to build complex labeling expressions.

Answer (score 5):

From the help on [Building label expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000):

> Field values are automatically cast to text strings. Therefore, if you
>   wish to use a numeric value in an arithmetic operation, or when making
>   a comparison, you will need to cast it back to a numeric data type.
>   The examples below add two integer fields:

Also, you need to pass two parameters to your function because you are referencing two different fields.

Parser:

`Python`

Expression:

```py
def FindLabel ([NAME], [WIDTH]):
  if int([WIDTH]) > 30:
    return [NAME]
```

Comment: Paul, your solution also worked for me.  I wish I could mark both as the correct answer, but since you gave a nod to Jens, s/he got the green check.  Thanks.